# shorthand to add an attribute to multiple variables

Tags: jquery

I haven't been able to find anywhere in which you can add/remove an attribute to multiple variables.

```
var sub = $('#sub');
var sub1 = $('#sub1');

$(sub, sub1).removeClass('error');
```

Comment: you can change your selector : $('#sub , #sub1').removeClass('error');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$(sub).add(sub1).removeClass('error');
```